# ng-hide ng-show clarification needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two forms in my one page client side web app in angular js/javascript

I got two forms

```
<form class="simple-form" ng-submit="createuser()">
Log in As: 
  <input type="text" ng-model="name.username">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The createuser() method is basically pushing an object into an array of objects.

```
$scope.createuser = function createuser() {
        var safer = angular.copy($scope.name);  
        $scope.users.push(safer);};

$scope.users = [
    {'username': 'John'},
    {'username': 'Dan'},
    {'username': 'Judy'}, 
    {'username': 'Michael'},
    {'username': 'Rebecca'},
    {'username': 'Macy'},
    {'username': 'Ross'}
    ];
```

I have another form that is a message container, basically I want the submit message to show only when a new user got created

```
<div class="message_container">
    <p ng-repeat="message in messages">
        {{message.post}}
    </p>
    <form class="post-form" ng-submit="postmessage()" ng-show="createuser()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="message.post">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to use ng-hide and ng-show for this.
I am thinking that the form should show when the ng-submit="createuser()"
The createuser() ended up creating some users blank ones because its a method and its looking for an expression. should I be using ng-show and ng-hide, maybe I should use something else instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` need an expression to determine their status. You could set a flag to `true` when you create a new user:

```
$scope.createuser = function createuser() {
    var safer = angular.copy($scope.name);  
    $scope.users.push(safer);
    $scope.isNewUser = true;
}

<form class="post-form" ng-submit="postmessage()" ng-show="isNewUser">
```